# C# Not Determining Type Arguments

Tags: c#, .net, generic-type-argument, generic-type-parameters

I have a C# method that is requiring explicit type arguments, and I am getting this error:

`error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Test.TargetMethod<TObjectFactory, TResult>(TObjectFactory)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

I can normally work around this by specifying proper arguments (regular arguments, not type arguments), but in this case, I may have to state the type arguments explicitly. But I don't want to specify type arguments since it adds verbosity.

Please see the below example code, specifically the two calls to `TargetMethod` near the bottom. In the first invocation of `TargetMethod`, the type arguments should be obvious since I'm passing in a `StringFactory`, which only returns a `string`.  (See the generic type constraints of `TargetMethod`.) Is there a way to get C# to realize that it has all it needs to know and shouldn't need type arguments? I'm wondering if I need to change the signature of `TargetMethod` so C# can understand what's happening. Thank you.

```
public interface IObjectFactory<out TResult>
{
    TResult Construct();
}

public class StringFactory : IObjectFactory<string>
{
    public string Construct() { return ""; }
}

public static class Test
{
    //I need to be able to pass in a generic factory to this method.
    //I also need it to return a generic result.
    //This is a mandatory part of the design, and on its own, it works fine.
    private static TResult TargetMethod<TObjectFactory, TResult>(TObjectFactory objectFactory)
        where TObjectFactory : IObjectFactory<TResult>
    {
        return objectFactory.Construct();
    }

    //This method can't easily call the other one.
    public static void EntryMethod()
    {
        StringFactory stringFactory = new StringFactory();
        //On the below line, how can I get C# to figure out that TargetMethod will return a string?
        string result1 = TargetMethod(stringFactory);//compilation error
        //I can do the below, but I don't want to have to specify type arguments each time.
        string result2 = TargetMethod<StringFactory, string>(stringFactory);
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/92

Comment: @Charlieface, that's helpful, but C# could know what my return type should be without type of the variable declaration. It can just look at the interface in the first parameter. Maybe I'll propose it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> On the below line, how can I get C# to figure out that TargetMethod will return a string?

You can't. Look at your method declaration:

```cs
TResult TargetMethod<TObjectFactory, TResult>(TObjectFactory objectFactory)
```

Your parameters *only* refer to `TObjectFactory`, not `TResult`. Type inference *only* uses the arguments and parameters, not how the method result is used or the type constraints for the type parameters. Even though `TObjectFactory` is *constrained* to implement `IObjectFactory<TResult>`, that isn't used to infer the type argument for `TResult`.

The type argument for `TResult` simply can't be inferred from the regular arguments, because the type parameter doesn't occur anywhere in the parameter list.

An alternative would be to change the method to:

```cs
TResult TargetMethod<TResult>(IObjectFactory<TResult> factory)
```

After all, you don't really need to know `TObjectFactory` in your method, as far as we can see.

(Or more simply, get rid of the interface entirely and use `Func<T>`, just using simple factory methods and constructing delegates from them where required...)

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping the system could examine the type constraints and conclude what a human can clearly see. I guess it's just a limitation of C#. Regarding your proposed alternative, that's not going to work in my case. As I mentioned, using both type parameters in `TargetMethod` is mandatory. But thank you very much once again.